# Get developer token for Adwords

Tags: google-ads-api

I have just a quick question regarding the usage of the adwords api. I would like to write a very small piece of software that uses those api, but when I try to obtain the token, within the procedure a required field is the website...but I have none!

Am i wrong in something? Is there any way to easily obtain the token?

Thank you!